# An error occurred during the upgrade:

Tags: php, sql

An error occurred during the upgrade: `` ALTER TABLE `gp_categories` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT [nativecode=1075 ** Un seul champ automatique est permis et il doit être indexé] ``

i got the above error.. kindly do the needful thanks in advance.

```
function query($sql, $params = array()) {
global $db;

$res = $db->query($sql, $params);
if ((new PEAR)->isError($res))
  show_error('An error occurred during the upgrade: ' . $res->getUserInfo());
return $res;
```

}

Comment: you've already got an auto_increment field in that table, and only ONE is permitted per-table, and it has to be indexed as well. generally that'd be your primary key field.

Comment: @Marc B thanks a lot.. it worked.

Answer (score 0):

assign **primary key** to the any column.